# Error registering package in Visual Studio 11

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I try to register a visual studio package using regpkg in Visual Studio 11 RC, I get the following error:

```
regpkg.exe /root:Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0 /codebase myvspackage.dll
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=2.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
system cannot find the file specified.
```

This worked fine with previous versions of Visual Studio. I'm working in a clean virtual machine that only has Visual Studio 2012 RC.

I've been surfing the web looking for a solution with no success.

If I just copy the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.dll in my app location it works fine, but this dll is not redistributable, so... what's the right way of registering a package in Visual Studio 11?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Luis

Comment: What are you trying to use from Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.dll?  It lives in PrivateAssemblies and, to the best of my knowledge, is not intended to be referenced from extensions.

Comment: That's what I wanted to mean; we cannot distribute that library by ourselves, so it seems that there's something missing in VS 2012 or VS 2012 SDK, that should include that library in order to register packages.

Comment: Basically we use that library to develop a plugin for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you also posted this to the MSDN forums since a question with identical text was posted there which I answered yesterday.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/96556cd4-44dd-4e01-8198-b83a66c6df26

In short it sounds like you have an explicit reference to v2 of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.dll, James is incorrect in saying you aren't supposed to use this, this is simply MPF from 2005. Referencing it is perfectly fine. If you have an explicit version in the reference in the project file try dropping it, if not try adding the binding redirect mentioned in my MSDN forum post.

I have started a mail with the SDK team about this issue though I don't know if they will be taking any changes this close to release. Also, as an FYI, since Shell.dll is from 2005, it is nearing the end of its supported life, we generally support three versions of previous VS releases.

On release of 2012 the support will be 2008,2010, 2012. I suspect in the next release (after 2012) we may stop including Shell.dll (the 2005 version) entirely in the shipped product.  Unless you need to run downlevel on say 2005 I would update the reference to one of the newer shell assemblies (like 9.0, 10.0 or 11.0)

Comment: I'll answer you in the MSDN forums as it's more appropriate. Thank you very much for your response.